# How to create global namespace/class in TypeScript that can be used in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My TypeScript and plain JavaScript code need to share a namespace and some data. TypeScript should "prepare" a namespace, external JS provides data, TypeScript processes it.

The context is an Angular 2 application. The loading order is:

1. Angular 2 app with its JavaScript starts
2. a custom external JavaScript file is dynamically loaded from an external source ([JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) style)
3. Angular 2 app does further processing on the data generated by the loaded JS file

Currently in the external JavaScript file I'm doing something like this:

```
if (typeof Blog === 'undefined')
{
    Blog = {
        Posts: []
    }
}
// ...
Blog.Posts.push(post);
```

In my Angular 2 app this JavaScript file is being dynamically loaded and the value then accessed like this:

```
declare var Blog: any;
...
let firstPost = Blog.Posts[0];
```

This works, I can access data placed by the external JS.

Now I want to keep the JavaScript part as minimal as possible. So I want to **move the declaration of `Blog` and `Posts` to TypeScript**, preferably so that it can be used there in a strongly typed fashion.

So I wish my JavaScript looked like this:

```
// ...
Blog.Posts.push(post);
```

Note the missing declaration of `Blog`. I tried something like this in TypeScript:

```
declare var Blog: BlogClass; // <- this is probably wrong, can be changed to anything necessary to make it work...
// ...
Blog = new BlogClass();
```

But apparently its not that easy. My Angular 2 app dies on me with a generic error message. The error is caused by `Blog = new BlogClass()`.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: What exactly is 'generic error message', and how and where BlogClass is defined?

Comment: @artem Doesn't matter because it's probably wrong. My takeaway so far is, that this declared variable cannot be assigned to. But if this is indeed possible then I stand corrected and there could be declared anything that would correspond to the JS namespace.


I also tried it with `declare var Blog: any` and then `Blog = 1;` which gives the same error message (telling me it's not allowed). The message is always 'EXCEPTION: Unable to set property 'message' of undefined or null reference', if that helps.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I thought 'move the declaration of Blog to TypeScript' means that its definition (the actual `var Blog` statement that defines global variable) stays on javascript side. If that's not the case, just remove `declare` from `var Blog` line in typescript code.

Comment: @artem Just tried using `var Blog` without the 'declare' and this removes the error (which is something!). But I still cannot access the variable in the browser console. Which should be possible if the TypeScript declaration actually created the namespace :-/

Comment: @artem Strange. Looking at the generated main.bundle.js I can see "var Blog;" being declared. I think I'm near and just removing "declare" will somehow be the key part.

Comment: Is there anything like `namespace` or `export` or `import` at the lop level in that typescript file before `var Blog`? That may affect the scope where `Blog` is declared in generated javascript code.

Comment: @artem Ha, looking at `main.bundle.js` `Blog` is declared within `function(module, exports, __webpack_require__)` - now is this done by TS or by Angular? But this explains why it cannot be accessed in the global namespace. Because it is not in it. And I moved the var declaration to the top - nothing above it.

Comment: It's done by typescript, that's the way is compiles typescript into modules suitable for bundler  (webpack) or module loader. The only way to reach global scope from within module is via some already-existing global object. That is, adding `(window as any).Blog = Blog;` assignment might help.

Comment: @artem That's it! `(window as any).Blog = new BlogClass();` - defined in the global scope, accessible from JS and typed in TS. Although it feels a bit dirty. But anyway, this should be your answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`declare` means that the thing being declared must be defined somewhere else.

```
declare var Blog: BlogClass;
```

does not produce any code in the resulting javascript, so this assignment

```
Blog = new BlogClass();
```

fails at runtime because `Blog` does not exist.

When you remove `declare`, this line appears in the generated code:

```
var Blog;
```

However, it does not necessarily create `var Blog` in global scope - when you compile typescript code as modules, it will be created inside a module and will be inaccessible to external javascript code, unless you go through the route of exporting it from typescript module and importing that module in your javacsript code.

The simplest (but a bit dirty) way to make sure that an object is created in  global scope is to do that explicitly:

```
(window as any).Blog = new BlogClass();
```